# Can accordion navigation be used without frames?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frame

For example suppose I have something like the following

http://jsfiddle.net/wxXav/

When a user clicks on a link within the accordion, I would like to direct them to the relevant content whilst preserving the current accordion navigation view.  Is this possible to do without frames?

Comment: sure. Use jQuery.cookie plugin to keep your accordion state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time the accordion changes you could keep the current state of the accordion navigation in a cookie.  Then on the next page load, just reproduce the state from said cookie.